# DataServiceContext adds odata.type to json body

Tags: c#, json, odata

When I'm using System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext to make calls to an odata service and I call the `Format.UseJson()` so that body would be sent as json instead of xml, everything looks fine except for some reason a odata.type is added that matches the EntityDescriptor which was added to the create\update object.

```
{
  "odata.type": "DEV1.services.SuppliersType",
  "Addresss": "w",
  "EmailAddress": "e",
  "SupplierID": "S005",
  "SupplierName": "q"
}
```

Then the service I'm calling ends up complaining about the odata.type proeprty not being know.
If I send below via Postman it works 100%

```
{
  "Addresss": "w",
  "EmailAddress": "e",
  "SupplierID": "S005",
  "SupplierName": "q"
}
```

Does anyone know of setting to tell it not to include the odata.type property but just send the properties of the entity